# Return JSON response from Flask view

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a function that analyzes a CSV file with Pandas and produces a dict with summary information. I want to return the results as a response from a Flask view. How do I return a JSON response?

```
@app.route("/summary")
def summary():
    d = make_summary()
    # send it back as json
```

Answer (score 1019, accepted):

A view can directly return a Python dict or list and Flask will call [`jsonify`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.json.jsonify) automatically.

```py
@app.route("/summary")
def summary():
    d = make_summary()
    return d
```

For older Flask versions, or to return a different JSON-serializable object, import and use [`jsonify`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.json.jsonify).

```py
from flask import jsonify

@app.route("/summary")
def summary():
    d = make_summary()
    return jsonify(d)
```

Answer (score 291):

`jsonify` serializes the data you pass it to JSON. If you want to serialize the data yourself, do what `jsonify` does by building a response with `status=200` and `mimetype='application/json'`.

```
from flask import json

@app.route('/summary')
def summary():
    data = make_summary()
    response = app.response_class(
        response=json.dumps(data),
        status=200,
        mimetype='application/json'
    )
    return response
```

Answer (score 163):

Pass keyword arguments to [`flask.jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.json.jsonify) and they will be output as a JSON object.

```
@app.route('/_get_current_user')
def get_current_user():
    return jsonify(
        username=g.user.username,
        email=g.user.email,
        id=g.user.id
    )
```

```javascript
{
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "admin@localhost",
    "id": 42
}
```

If you already have a dict, you can pass it directly as `jsonify(d)`.

Answer (score 53):

If you don't want to use `jsonify` for some reason, you can do what it does manually. Call `flask.json.dumps` to create JSON data, then return a response with the `application/json` content type.

```
from flask import json

@app.route('/summary')
def summary():
    data = make_summary()
    response = app.response_class(
        response=json.dumps(data),
        mimetype='application/json'
    )
    return response
```

`flask.json` is distinct from the built-in `json` module. It will use the faster `simplejson` module if available, and enables various integrations with your Flask app.

Comment: how   `app.response_class` differ from `flask.make_response`?

Answer (score 46):

To return a JSON response and set a status code you can use `make_response`:

```
from flask import jsonify, make_response

@app.route('/summary')
def summary():
    d = make_summary()
    return make_response(jsonify(d), 200)
```

Inspiration taken from this [comment](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/478#issuecomment-166723852) in the Flask issue tracker.

Answer (score 29):

As of version 1.1.0 Flask, [if a view returns a dict it will be turned into a JSON response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#apis-with-json).

```
@app.route("/users", methods=['GET'])
def get_user():
    return {
        "user": "John Doe",
    }
```

Answer (score 20):

If you want to analyze a file uploaded by the user, the Flask [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) shows how to get files from users and access them. Get the file from `request.files` and pass it to the summary function.

```
from flask import request, jsonify
from werkzeug import secure_filename

@app.route('/summary', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def summary():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv = request.files['data']
        return jsonify(
            summary=make_summary(csv),
            csv_name=secure_filename(csv.filename)
        )

    return render_template('submit_data.html')
```

Replace the `'data'` key for `request.files` with the name of the file input in your HTML form.

Answer (score 17):

Flask 1.1.x supports returning a JSON dict without calling `jsonify`. If you want to return something besides a dict, you still need to call `jsonify`.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return {
        "api_stuff": "values",
    }
```

is equivalent to

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return jsonify({
        "api_stuff": "values",
    })
```

See the pull request that added this: https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/3111

Answer (score 13):

I use a decorator to return the result of `jsonfiy`. I think it is more readable when a view has multiple returns. This does not support returning a tuple like `content, status`, but I handle returning error statuses with `app.errorhandler` instead.

```
import functools
from flask import jsonify

def return_json(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def inner(**kwargs):
        return jsonify(f(**kwargs))

    return inner

@app.route('/test/<arg>')
@return_json
def test(arg):
    if arg == 'list':
        return [1, 2, 3]
    elif arg == 'dict':
        return {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    elif arg == 'bool':
        return True
    return 'none of them'
```

Answer (score 6):

In Flask 1.1, if you return a dictionary and it will automatically be converted into JSON.  So if `make_summary()` returns a dictionary, you can

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/summary')
def summary():
    d = make_summary()
    return d
```

The [SO that asks about including the status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412228/flask-sending-data-and-status-code-through-a-response-object/45412576) was closed as a duplicate to this one.  So to also answer that question, you can include the status code by returning a tuple of the form `(dict, int)`. The `dict` is converted to JSON and the `int` will be the HTTP Status Code.  Without any input, the Status is the default 200.  So in the above example the code would be 200.  In the example below it is changed to 201.

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/summary')
def summary():
    d = make_summary()
    return d, 201  # 200 is the default
```

You can check the status code using

```sh
curl --request GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/summary" -w "\ncode: %{http_code}\n\n"
```

Answer (score 5):

Prior to Flask 0.11, `jsonfiy` would not allow returning an array directly. Instead, pass the list as a keyword argument.

```
@app.route('/get_records')
def get_records():
    results = [
        {
          "rec_create_date": "12 Jun 2016",
          "rec_dietary_info": "nothing",
          "rec_dob": "01 Apr 1988",
          "rec_first_name": "New",
          "rec_last_name": "Guy",
        },
        {
          "rec_create_date": "1 Apr 2016",
          "rec_dietary_info": "Nut allergy",
          "rec_dob": "01 Feb 1988",
          "rec_first_name": "Old",
          "rec_last_name": "Guy",
        },
    ]
    return jsonify(results=list)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the same when using Flask's class-based views.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask.views import MethodView

app = Flask(__name__)

class Summary(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        d = make_summary()
        return jsonify(d)

app.add_url_rule('/summary/', view_func=Summary.as_view('summary'))
```

Answer (score 1):

if its a dict, flask can return it directly (Version 1.0.2)

```
def summary():
    d = make_summary()
    return d, 200
```

Answer (score 1):

To serialize an object, use `jsonify` from `flask` module to jsonify the object, a dictionary gets serialized by default. Also, if you're dealing with files you can always use `make_response`.

Comment: This doesn't add much to the existing answers, which show how to use `jsonify` and `make_response` and offer deeper insights.

Answer (score 0):

I like this way:

```py
    @app.route("/summary")
    def summary():
        responseBody = { "message": "bla bla bla", "summary": make_summary() }
        return make_response(jsonify(responseBody), 200)
```

Comment: Why do you like it that way? What makes this better than just returning `responseBody`? (BTW, best to use `snake_case` per PEP-8).

Comment: This is useful when you want to customise your response code.