# How to interface JQuery with Flask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension that uses a `jQuery.post()` call to send data to an external website.  The external website handles the data using a Flask endpoint and generates a result.  Unfortunately I am not sure how to transfer the result back to the client.  How can I do this?

I've tried using a `render_template` call within Flask, like so:

```
app.route("/my_endpoint", methods = ['POST'])
def my_endpoint():
    print ('hi')  # this statement prints
    results = ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # want to eventually replace this with
        # return render_template("results.html", results=results)
        return render_template("test.html")
```

But this doesn't actually load the page `test.html`.

I've also tried transferring the data back to the Chrome extension using a callback (which I would prefer not to do if possible), as in

```
post_results = function(input_data) {
    jQuery.post("my_flask_endpoint",
        input_data,
        function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            ...
        }
```

But I'm not sure what to put in the callback function, because it seems like "data" is a bunch of HTML, and I don't know how to load pages given only an HTML string (as opposed to the URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that `data` is a bunch of HTML, because that's exactly what you sent it! `render_template` is the Jinja2 function you use to show a given page to a user, and in the end, all that is is HTML. What you are doing is returning the HTML rendering of `test.html` as the data.

What (I think) you are trying to do, is either return the "results" object, *or* trigger a redirect to `/results` after `POST`ing to `/my_endpoint`?

Depending on what you plan to do with the data, you could go either way.

If you are wanting to return the data to the users current page/the jQuery callback, try just returning `results` as JSON (assuming results is a dictionary). A more detailed explanation of `jsonify` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081532/how-to-return-json-using-flask-web-framework)

```
return flask.jsonify(**results)
```

Alternatively, if you plan to navigate to a different page to show the results, you need to decide whether you want Flask to perform the redirection and render the data using results.html as a template, or pass the results to the client and have it navigate and transfer the received data itself.