# GET / HTTP/1.1 404 error

Tags: python, json, flask, steam

I am trying to make a steam flask response in order to get a user`s friends and games

I keep getting the `GET / HTTP/1.1` 404 error.

Any advice on how to fix it?
Also, how can I get a json response instead of flask?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from steamapi import core, user
app = Flask("Steamer")
core.APIConnection(api_key="apikeygoeshere")
@app.route('/user/<name>')
def hello(name=None):
try:
    try:
        steam_user = user.SteamUser(userid=int(useridgoeshere))
    except ValueError:
        steam_user = user.SteamUser(userurl=usernamegoeshere)
    name = steam_user.name
    content = "Your real name is {0}. You have {1} friends and {2} games.".format(steam_user.real_name,
                                                                              len(steam_user.friends),
                                                                              len(steam_user.games))
    img = steam_user.avatar
    return jsonify('hello.html', name=name, content=content, img=img)
except Exception as ex:
    return jsonify('hello.html', name=name)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Not sure if this has any impact on the error, but the hello.html code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<title>Hello there!</title>
{% if name %}
  <h1>Hello {% if img %}<img src="{{ img }}" /> {% endif %}{{ name }}!</h1>
{% else %}
  <h1>Hello Anonymous!</h1>
{% endif %}
{% if content %}
  <p>{{ content }}</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Response i get:

`* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2016 17:26:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: Instead of adding a link to a screenshot with your code, copy your code in your question. That will make things clearer.

Comment: Regarding how to get a JSON response using Flask, have a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13089975/1805725)