# Internal Server Error from Flask

Tags: python, api, flask

Back again here with a flask question. I am a beginner and learn some awesome things from reddit (how to legit code).
Here is my code that I have grabbed certain information from an API that I am now trying to host locally through flask.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

import httplib

import json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')

def index():

    connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('api.football-data.org')

    headers = {'X-Auth-Token': 'this is my api token here', 'X-Response-Control': 'minified'}
    connection.request('GET', '/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable', None, headers)
    response = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read().decode())
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run 127.0.0.1:5000 I get:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Here is what my server is telling me!

```
MacBooks-MBP:Football macbookpro13$ python Footy_Web.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2016-12-20 13:58:17,493] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1642, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1746, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 847, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 871, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Dec/2016 13:58:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I should mention this code works outside of the flask framework!

Comment: I am not familiar with flask (but Django instead). My guess is you are trying to send back dict type object `response `. But you need to send HTTP Response. You may google on *how to send dict as response to Flask API* which gave me result: [How to return json using Flask web framework](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13089975/2063361)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a valid `HTTP` response. To do so, you can use `jsonify` like below:

```
return jsonify(response)
```

Do not forget to import `jsonify` like this:

```
from flask import jsonify
```

`jsonify()` returns a `flask.Response()` object.

You can also use `json.dumps()`, but in this case you need to add a `http` status code and a `Content-Type` header to return a valid `HTTP` response:

```
return json.dumps(response), 200, {'content-type': 'application/json'}
```