# python as Backend and HTML as front end

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am building a simple web application using HTML and Python to display image on canvas. Also I am using Flask framework for it.
Where Image is uploaded from HTML and processed it in Opencv(Python) and then displayed on HTML made canvas, 
what I have done so far is uploaded image only. But I couldn't displayed on canvas.

here is the CSS and HTML code

```css
p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
h2 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/test.css">
        <title>
            CV - Rogier
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>
            Study
        </h3>
        <p>
            <form action="/hello" method="post">
           Asset Tag:<br>
           <input type = "file" id = "Image"> 
           <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
       var x = document.getElementById("Image");
       x.disabled = true;
    }
    </script>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </p>       
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>   
<script>
var n = document.getElementById("Image")
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText(n, 10, 50);
</script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

And Python code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html')

@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            image = request.form['Image']
            get_image = cv2.imread(image,0)
            return cv2.imshow(get_image)
        else:
            return render_template('test.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = 'localhost', port = 3000, debug=True)
```

please tell me what I am missing and whats wrong!! Thanks

Comment: Do you want to safe the image on the server? If not you don't have to use a submit, just load the image with js and display it. Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: @DomenikReitzner Actually after I upload an Image, I want to process it and save it on server.

Comment: ok, and then you want to display it if it was saved correctly?

Comment: @DomenikReitzner yeah!!

Comment: So I would implement the safe functionality first (send the file with post) and then display the image if you get a "success message"

Comment: @DomenikReitzner yeah sort of. How can we do that?? Do you any solution on it?

Comment: We shouldn't write the code for you. Please ask a question to a specific and not to general topic. We are glad to help, when you get stuck along the way, but you still need to do your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post your image with [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) (readAsDataURL).

Write your image into a [file with python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) (beware of base64 encoding)

Then return a [Json with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081532/return-json-response-from-flask-view) (either error or success)

Display image or error message depending on result from server.

I hope this is enough information. Happy coding

Comment: Ok I will do that.