# Flask response stream multiple values

Tags: python, flask, response

I'm trying to setup a flask video streaming server based on the code from [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask):

```
from camera_utils import Camera

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html', endpoint='video_feed', source=1)


def gen_feed(camera):
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()['frame']
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed/<path:source>')
def video_feed(source):
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen_feed(Camera(source)),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

The `index.html` template includes a line :

```
<img src="{{ url_for(endpoint, source=source) }}">
```

Now, my function `camera.get_frame()` returns a dict with the frame as a jpg string and some additional information (e.g. `camera.get_frame()['fps']`). What would be the best way to display this information on the webpage so that it's updated each time a frame is retrieved?

EDIT : [Return JSON response from Flask view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081532/return-json-response-from-flask-view) is nice but a more specific answer would be appreciated as a Flask beginner. How to put the dictionary in the generator, handle `mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace'` with jsonify and display the json object in my webpage?

Comment: Currently wrestle with exactly the same issue. Do you possibly have any solution now?