# When you return a dict in flask, is jsonify automatically applied?

Tags: python, json, flask

It appears that this works:

```
@app.route('/my/route/')
def my_route():
    return {
        'Something': True,
        'Else': None,
        'Thingy': 12345,
        'Blah': 'Blah'
    }
```

When I visit the route in a browser, I get valid JSON like this:

```
{
    "Something": true, 
    "Else": null, 
    "Thingy": 12345
    "Blah": "Blah", 
}
```

Everything is converted to valid JSON, but I haven't seen any documentation supporting this. I'm not even importing the jsonify module. Is this ok?

Comment: In current, vanilla versions of Flask this does not seem to be valid. It results in a TypeError and "The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a dict."

Comment: @jarmod I think I'm using vanilla Flask. I'm not sure how it's returning the JSON in this case. I did it by accident really.

Comment: Typically you would import jsonify, and then return jsonify({...}).

Answer (score 2):

No, returning a dict in Flask will not apply `jsonify` automatically. In fact, Flask route cannot return dictionary.

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return {
        'Something': True,
        'Else': None,
        'Thingy': 12345,
        'Blah': 'Blah'
    }
```

Output:

```
TypeError
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a dict.
```

Screenshot:

[image: showing error for returning dictionary]

As the traceback indicates route's return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable.

Comment: As of Flask `1.1.0` you can return a dictionary, or still use `jsonify()` for other data types.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58917715/2052575) and [these docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#apis-with-json).

Answer (score 0):

define the custom json encoder! it will do the trick!

```
import flask
import datetime

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

class CustomJSONEncoder(flask.json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if   isinstance(obj, datetime.date): return obj.isoformat()
        try:
            iterable = iter(obj)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        else:
            return tuple(iterable)

        return flask.json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

app.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder
```