# return existing JSON file in flask

Tags: python, json, flask

i have a method (`matching`) that returns a JSON file. I want to return this file via a flask method.

when i do this:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def json_example():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    request_text = req_data['request'] #json text that is needed as argument for calling the matching method
    json_result = matching(request_text)
    return json_result
```

i get this error:

```
<title>TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple,
    Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a TextIOWrapper. // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
```

playing around with `str(json_result`), i just get this:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='result.json' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Also, `jsonify(json_reslult)` does not work, since i have a json file and am not trying to convert a string into a json. when trying it gives:

```
<title>TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
```

Any helpis greatly appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081532/return-json-response-from-flask-view

Comment: @Marco doesn't work, because i already have a json, i dont need to convert my string into a json but return my json

Comment: How abut this: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JSON/#encoding

Comment: didnt work either, sadly

Comment: try this: return json_result.read()

Answer (score 0):

Decode request_text first

```
json_result = matching(json.loads(request_text))
```