# My Flask app is running into a couple of errors regarding not being able to find resource

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Hello I am having a hard time trying to get my survey app to work. Run I run the flask app it gives me a couple of errors.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) :5000/favicon.ico:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) :5000/test:1
```

This is the error in the terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tannerormanoski/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/tannerormanoski/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/tannerormanoski/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/tannerormanoski/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/tannerormanoski/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/tannerormanoski/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/tannerormanoski/Documents/Survey_2/Input_Saving_Test/app.py", line 21, in test
    result = json.load(output) # This converts the json output to a python dictionary
  File "/Users/tannerormanoski/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Sep/2022 08:45:15] "POST /test HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Sep/2022 08:45:45] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

This is my app.py

```
import json

from flask import request

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__,
            static_folder='static',
            template_folder='templates')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    output = request.get_json()
    print(output) # This is the output that was stored in the JSON within the browser
    print(type(output))
    result = json.load(output) # This converts the json output to a python dictionary
    print(result) # Printing the new dictionary
    print(type(result)) # This shows the json converted as a pyhthon dictionary
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the snippet from my app.js file

```
let persons = [];

const addPerson = (ev)=>{
    ev.preventDefault(); //stop form from submitting
    let person = {
        name: document.getElementById("name").value,
        title: document.getElementById("title").value,
        role: document.getElementById("role").value,
        reports: document.getElementById("reportsTo").value,
        fact: document.getElementById("funFact").value
    }
    persons.push(person);
    document.forms[0].reset(); // to clear the form for the next entries

    //for display purposes only 
    console.warn('added' , {persons} );
    let pre = document.querySelector('#msg pre');
    pre.textContent = '\n' + JSON.stringify(persons, '\t', 2);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/test',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(persons)
    });
```

It seems to be where '/test' app route, as in the url in the app.js file it does not underline the link as it normally would. I am newer to coding and very new with flask, so I am having trouble diagnosing the problem myself.

If it helps my file structure is

```
   >static
        app.js
        style.css
        >Images
    >templates
        index.html
        app.py
```

Comment: Don't post images of code, errors, etc... Add them as text in your question.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for details.

Comment: Please include the *full error traceback*, not just the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your templates folder is expecting only template files (.html files).
It's standard to have your app.py file in the root of your project.
Your structure should look like this. Same w/ your app.js file.

```
>static
    style.css
    >Images
>templates
    index.html
app.py
app.js
```

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/layout/

Edit1:
Also, it may not be valid to return the python dictionary like that.
Try creating a response before returning, I've had to use this when returning pdf files, etc.

```
from flask import json

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST','GET])
def test():
    output = request.get_json()
    print(f'output: {output}, output type: {type(output)}')
    response = app.response_class(
        response=json.dumps(output),
        status=200,
        mimetype='application/json'
    )
    return response
```

reference material:
[Return JSON response from Flask view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081532/return-json-response-from-flask-view)

Comment: @TannerOrmanoski did it end up working for you?

Comment: I used your code and it worked, just wanted to say thanks*100 again

Comment: I'm glad I could help! @TannerOrmanoski 
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Here is a link describing in more detail what you should do when someone answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.