# Error 400 for api request after deploy from localhost to PythonAnyWhere

Tags: python, api, flask, python-requests, pythonanywhere

I am trying to create easy demo example for REST API using Flask. My code is Ok when I am testing it from ***localhost***. But been deployed with ***Pythonanywhere*** free account, I have 400 Error. I.e. requests without params still works properly, but only GET requests with params start to give 400.

```
   response = requests.get(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
        params=params
    )
```

Here is the proving - **api.openweathermap.org** is in the whitelist
[image]

any help please?

This is the part of final code

```
import requests

URL = "http://demoapi.pythonanywhere.com"

def printer(method, requests_answer):
    print(F"{requests_answer=} for {method=}")
    if requests_answer:
        print(F"{requests_answer.text}")
        try:
            print(F"{requests_answer.json()=}")
        except:
            print('json is not present')
    print("\n", 30*"*^")
    

response = requests.get(URL)
printer('GET' ,response)

response = requests.get(URL + '/data/weather/Львів')
printer('GET', response)

params = dict(city_name='Львів')
response = requests.get(URL + '/data/weather', params=params)
printer('GET', response)
```

So  `requests.get(URL)`  and `requests.get(URL + '/data/weather/Львів')` is still Ok, but   `requests.get(URL + '/data/weather', params=params)` gives 400.

Please say any when give me MINUS for this question...

***P.S. My investigations show - only PUT and POST work on Pythonanywhere host, GET and DELETE gives 400.  At localhost the same code works properly with GET POST PUT DELETE. The same code.***

Code for interesting readers. Say again.  This code wors properly:

```
import requests

NO_PROXY = {
    'no': 'pass',
}

URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'


def printer(method, requests_answer):
    print(F"{requests_answer=} for {method=}")
    if requests_answer:
        print(F"{requests_answer.text}")
        try:
            print(F"{requests_answer.json()=}")
        except:
            print('json is not present')
    print("\n", 30*"*^")
    

response = requests.get(URL, proxies=NO_PROXY)
printer('GET' ,response)

response = requests.get(URL + '/data/weather/Львів', proxies=NO_PROXY)
printer('GET', response)

params = dict(city_name='Львів')
response = requests.get(URL + '/data/weather', params=params, proxies=NO_PROXY)
printer('GET', response)
```

and  PARTIALY wrong  if `URL = "http://demoapi.pythonanywhere.com"`

Here is the server full code if needed

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, make_response
#  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081532/return-json-response-from-flask-view

from get_weather_by_cityname import get_city_weather

app = Flask(__name__)

prohibited_city_names ={
    1: 'Днепр',
    2: 'Киев',
    3: 'Львов',
    4: 'Одесса',
}

def my_jsonify(json_text: str):
    resp = make_response(json_text)
    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'  
    return resp   


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/api')
def index():
    return """<h1>  Опис ІПЗ визначення поточної погоди за назвою міста!  </h1>
    <p>  <i><b>Користуємось так:</i></b></p>
    <p>  https:/demoapi.pythonanywhere.com/data/weather/Львів</p>
    <p>  <i><b>Отримуємо таке:</i></b></p>
    <pre>  
    {
    "погода описово": "хмарно",
    "температура, C": 8.22,
    "температура відчувається як": 5.24,
    "атмосферний тиск": 1022,
    "вологість повітря": 72,
    "відсоток неба в хмарах": 100
    }
    </pre>
    """ 



@app.route('/data/weather/<city_name>', methods=['GET'])
def get_wether_in_town(city_name):
    city_name = city_name.strip()
    if city_name not in prohibited_city_names.values():
        return my_jsonify(get_city_weather(city_name))
    else:
        return 'Помилка в назві міста ...'


@app.route('/data/weather', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    print(F'--------get_data, {request.json=}   {request.args.get("city_name")=}', flush=True)
    city_name = request.args.get("city_name")
    if city_name:
        if city_name not in prohibited_city_names.values():
            print(request.json, flush=True)
            return my_jsonify(get_city_weather(city_name))
        else:
            return 'Помилка в назві міста ...'
    else:
        print(F'--------get_data, {request.json=}', flush=True)
        return jsonify(prohibited_city_names)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: The 400 error response might have a readable body that explains the error. This code hardly constitutes a MCVE, the error could be in the contents of the params.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні Look. I've said. The code works properly when I am testing from IDE on localhost. It gives expected result.  BUT when I'll try the same from Pythonanywhere hosting request with params gives 400. Yes You right. Героям Слава

Comment: But the final code does not use api.openweather. In any case you want to print the `response.text` for the failed response.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні  -  Ive placed the `server` code for my question now )
Thanks for been patiant )

Comment: What does your print in the first line of `get_data` show?

Comment: @GilesThomas  nothing when placed on pythonanywhere  and:

--------get_data, request.json=None   request.args.get("city_name")='Львів'

from localhost

Comment: @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
-----

response.headers = {'Date': 'Sun, 09 Apr 2023 17:54:28 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '167', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'PythonAnywhere'}
----
Look. My OS is Wimdows.   PythonAnywhere - Linux.
Some encoding problems may be?

Comment: I'd recommend adding "flush=True" as a kwarg at the end of your prints on PythonAnywhere; it might just be that Python is buffering output.